# Drawn symbol recognition: How to implement recognition

Tags: machine-learning, symbols

I try to implement a recognition of kanji that are drawn with the mouse. I have for each Kanji I intend to recognize exactly one sample file that provides all strokes with start and end position of the respective stroke (for a fixed image resolution).

I was wondering how I could use these stroke information for kanji recognition. I was thinking about using the slope between a strokes start and endpoint and using these as feature for machine learning, but with only one sample per kanji I would have ~2000 classes (one for each kanji) and a data sparsity problem (one set of stroke information for each kanji only). 
Is it possible to use ML on such a sparse data set?

Answer (score 0):

Your model may suffer from the sparsity of your data set however it should still be possibly to apply certain machine learning algorithms to it, particularly the simpler algorithms with lower numbers of parameters. (In short, try it and see).

The situation you have described however, doesn't seem to me as bad as it might at first glance. The task of determining which kanji based on an ordered set of identified strokes (I would guess) is fairly simple. The difficulty would lie in identifying the strokes to begin with.

As such, the machine learning task which really needs the data is the stroke identification. This model however has far more than one sample per class, as each stroke will likely appear in multiple kanji.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might get some inspiration from http://demos.shogun-toolbox.org/application/ocr/ (the source code for this is in the shogun distribution).

Then regarding a single kanji per class as training example: That won't work well when Kanjis are very similar. However, what you could do is the generate virtual examples that you generate by slightly distorting your kanji, i.e., sheering, rotating, scaling etc. That is what Yann and many others did on MNIST (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).